# Unable to create jmx file using proxycontrol in java

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I wrote a code in java to record HTTP Traffic in a browser using jmeter. However i'm unable to save the recorded traffic in jmx file.
I opened a port using the code and set the same port to the browser.
When i try to execute the code it throws an exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LogicControllerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.WorkBenchGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener;
import org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.RecordingController;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.RecordController;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JavaTestSamplerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.WorkBench;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree;

public class JmeterNewCode {

    public static void Initialize() {
        try {
            // get the property value
            String jmeterHome = "C:\\Users\\kumar\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\apache-jmeter-2.13";

            // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(JMeterUtils.getJMeterBinDir() + "\\jmeter.properties");
            // JMeterUtils.initLogging(); // you can comment this line out to
            // see

            // extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setLoopController(ThreadGroup threadGroup, int loop, boolean isEnabled) {

        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());

        loopController.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        loopController.setLoops(loop);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    }

    public static HTTPSamplerProxy CreateHTTPSampler() {
        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        sampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        sampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
        sampler.setEnabled(true);
        return sampler;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        Initialize();

        // JMeter Test Plan, basic all u JOrphan HashTree
        ListedHashTree testPlanTree = new ListedHashTree();

        // Test Plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setName("JMeter Script From Java Code");
        testPlan.setEnabled(true);
        testPlan.setFunctionalMode(false);
        testPlan.setSerialized(false);
        Arguments argument = new Arguments();
        argument.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables(argument);

        // Thread Group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
        setLoopController(threadGroup, 1, true);
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);

        /*
         * //Create HTTP Request HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = CreateHTTPSampler();
         * Arguments argument1 = new Arguments(); sampler.setName("HTTP Request"
         * ); sampler.setArguments(argument1);
         * sampler.setDomain("www.google.com"); sampler.setMethod("GET");
         * sampler.setFollowRedirects(true); sampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
         * sampler.setUseKeepAlive(true); sampler.setDoMultipartPost(false);
         * sampler.setMonitor(false); sampler.setImplementation("HttpClient4");
         */

        // Create Recording Controller to get the captured requests
        RecordingController rc = new RecordingController();
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, RecordingController.class.getName());
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, RecordController.class.getName());
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.ENABLED, true);
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.NAME, "Captured Requests");

        // Add Proxy control
        ProxyControl control = new ProxyControl();
        control.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ProxyControl.class.getName());
        control.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ProxyControlGui.class.getName());
        control.setProperty(TestElement.ENABLED, true);
        control.setProperty(TestElement.NAME, "HTTP TestScript Recorder");
        control.setPort("4444");
        control.setCaptureHttpHeaders(true);
        control.setGroupingMode(0);
        control.setAssertions(false);
        control.setSamplerRedirectAutomatically(false);
        control.setSamplerFollowRedirects(true);
        control.setUseKeepAlive(true);
        control.setSamplerDownloadImages(false);


        JMeterTreeModel jModel = new JMeterTreeModel(control, threadGroup);
        JMeterTreeListener jListener = new JMeterTreeListener(jModel);

        GuiPackage gPackage = GuiPackage.getInstance(jListener, jModel);

        JMeterTreeNode jNode = new JMeterTreeNode(rc, jModel);
        control.setTarget(jNode);

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        ListedHashTree threadGroupTree = (ListedHashTree) testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);

        // threadGroupTree.add(sampler);
        ListedHashTree controlTree = (ListedHashTree) threadGroupTree.add(control);
        threadGroupTree.add(rc);

        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\kumar\\Desktop\\New folder\\file1.jtl");
        String logJTLFile = f.getAbsolutePath();

        // Result Collector for View Results
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ResultCollector.class.getName());
        logger.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ViewResultsFullVisualizer.class.getName());
        logger.setProperty(TestElement.ENABLED, true);
        logger.setName("View Results");
        logger.setFilename(logJTLFile);
        SampleSaveConfiguration saveConfig = new SampleSaveConfiguration();
        saveConfig.setResponseData(true);
        saveConfig.setAssertions(true);
        saveConfig.setAssertionResultsFailureMessage(true);
        saveConfig.setAsXml(true);
        saveConfig.setDataType(true);
        saveConfig.setMessage(true);
        saveConfig.setRequestHeaders(true);
        saveConfig.setResponseData(true);
        saveConfig.setResponseHeaders(true);
        saveConfig.setSamplerData(true);
        saveConfig.setSuccess(true);
        saveConfig.setUrl(true);

        logger.setSaveConfig(saveConfig);

        threadGroupTree.add(logger);

        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree,
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\kumar\\Desktop\\New folder\\k.jmx"));

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        logger.testStarted();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        control.startProxy();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        control.stopProxy();
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

and the exception is

```
INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.e] (): All thread groups have been started
DEBUG   2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Subtracting node, stack size = 2
DEBUG   2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Subtracting node, stack size = 2
DEBUG   2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Subtracting node, stack size = 2
DEBUG   2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Subtracting node, stack size = 1
INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
ERROR   2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Test failed!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:576)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:567)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.685 [jmeter.t] (): Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
Exception in thread "Thread Group 1-1" INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.708 [jmeter.e] (): Notifying test listeners of end of test
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:589)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.710 [jmeter.r] (): Shutdown hook started
DEBUG   2016-03-04 22:25:12.710 [jmeter.r] (): Flushing: C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\New folder\file1.jtl
INFO    2016-03-04 22:25:12.710 [jmeter.r] (): Shutdown hook ended
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a design problem because the `ProxyControl` need that `GuiPackage.getInstance() != null & StandardJMeterEngine` run method (`org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted()`) need `GuiPackage.getInstance() == null OR GuiPackage.getInstance().getMainFrame() != null` but `MainFrame` is not easy to create because it needs libs from JMeter lib folder, you can see here `org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(String)`.

the solution is to have one process to create the jmx file and save it  and another one to create the `ProxyControl` and start it and another one to load the testplan and run it.